# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric in query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I want to call the `ID` of the row because I want to delete the row.

Here is my code:-

```
private void DeleteAttachment(string ID)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "DELETE FROM EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS WHERE mkey= @ID";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

protected void GrdTraining_DeleteCommand(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["dt10"] != null)
    {
        dt10 = (DataTable)Session["dt10"];
    }
    else
    {
        BindDatatable();
    }
    DeleteAttachment(ID);

    DataRow[] grdTrain = dt10.Select("SR_NO=" + Convert.ToString(e.Record["SR_NO"]));
    dt10.Rows.Remove(grdTrain[0]);
    AddToViewState("GrdTraining");
}
```

but I am unable to delete the row. When I tried to debug it, at `ID`, I was getting `_Page`.

The error message:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Please, suggest a way to call a dynamic ID.

Comment: Try adding with an explicit type rather than adding with value.

Comment: change the function `DeleteAttachment` argument to `int`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: how to add that ??

Comment: @vkp: added, but getting error while calling that function in the `delete` command

Comment: Read [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @juharr: thanks for the link, but for now how to achieve this

Comment: If the `mkey` column is numeric then use `int.Parse`, `int.TryParse`, or `Convert.ToInt32` to convert the `ID` to an `int`.  And use that value to set the `@ID` parameter.

Comment: @juharr: yes did like this `int ID = Convert.ToInt32(hiddelmkey.Value);` but getting error as **input sring is not in a correct format**

Comment: What is the specific data type of the `mkey` column?    Can you show the value of `hiddelmkey.Value`?  I was just guessing that you're working with integers, but maybe you need to use a different numerical type.

Comment: is mkey column in the sql table nvarchar?

Comment: @juharr: datatype of `mkey` is `decimal` in the sql table. Also while debugging the value  of `hiddelmkey.Value` was always `""`

Comment: @userDEV: no it is decimal

Comment: @juharr: any help on this sir ??

Comment: Make sure the value of ID is always a number and not null

Comment: @userDEV: yeah, but how to check that. any help

Comment: Sounds like you should use `decimal.TryParse`.  If it returns `false` then the `string` is not a valid decimal value.

Comment: use a try catch block.  display a message box to in the catch to see the value of ID

Comment: @userDEV It's better to avoid exceptions if possible and the `TryParse` methods are specifically made for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I think you need to do something like the following

```
private void DeleteAttachment(string ID)
{
    decimal numericId;
    if(!decimal.TryParse(ID, out numericId))
    {
        // The ID is not a valid decimal determine what to do in that case.
    }

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "DELETE FROM EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS WHERE mkey= @ID";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = numericId;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could change the `ID` argument to the `DeleteAttachment` method to be a `decimal` and do the parsing outside the method.

Comment: Sure sir, will try this one let u know.

Comment: Sir, i tried your code, but it was always going inside `if(!decimal.TryParse(ID, out numericId))
    {
        // The ID is not a valid decimal determine what to do in that case.
    }`

Comment: @nadeem Then the value you are trying to parse is not in a valid format.  Can you show an example of the value of the `ID`?

Comment: actually it worked, I made a small mistake that's why it was not working

Answer (score 0):

within the DeleteAttachment I would simply put:

```
decimal temp;
if (!Decimal.TryParse(ID, out temp)) { return; }
```